# Can't attach MySQL database with my web application

Tags: mysql, web-applications, tunnel, cloud-foundry, vmc

I am using the vmc tool to upload my web application to cloudfoundry. I have pushed my web aplication and created service to bind with. But I am getting a problem in tunneling it. I want to connect my database stored in backup file in my system with my web application. Here is the image where I entered the commands:

[image: error while tunneling in vmc]

I am having an error about path. I don't know how to resolve this. Please let me know how I should attach my databse with my web application.

Answer (score 2):

What the error is saying is that you need to have MySQL client on your build path. Caldecott (the application which gets executed when you type vmc tunnel) uses your own client for either MySQL, Postgres or Redis. If you do not have MySQL client installed or if you do not have it defined in your PATH environment variable, you will get this error.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not it but there's a space in your password string in the screenshot provided.

Besides that it seems that this error may be generated if the "build path" used for connecting to the database is incorrect. Manually check if the tunnel to the database works fine with those credentials and/or check to see if VMC can access other databases.

Comment: this is my first time ..i dont know much about it ..i just put that command ..rest all came by its own .. password too ..how i can connect my databsae with application ?

Comment: What Ali here said, I thought you already had the client. Go get the mySQL.exe client and move into to that path. It'll server as your DB provider, etc.